# Mixed RAM modules in a Mac Pro

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I'm considering buying some additional RAM for my Mac Pro.

I currently have 4GB installed as 4 x 1GB modules. I understand that Mac Pro RAM needs to be installed in matched pairs.

Am I able to install another 4GB s 2 x 2GB modules in addition to the 4 x 1GB that are already installed?

The 2GB modules will be matched - but they do not match the other modules, does this cause a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only each of the pairs needs to be matched pairs. The speed of the ram needs to be at least as fast as the original ram though.

The only remaining question is, do mac pro still comes with 8 memory slots (as when I first see them?)

Comment: The RAM I'm considering is DDR2-800, the same speed as the modules I already have installed. And as far as I'm aware, the Mac Pro I have (early 2008, quad core Xeon) has 2 memory riser cards with 4 slots each.